# XMS.Net : Setting the RFH2 on IMessage

Tags: ibm-mq, xms

I am developing an application which sends message to MQ Queuemanager using XMS.Net. One of the requirement is to set custom RFH2 value . I am unable to figure this out.

How do we set RFH2 for IMessage using XMS.net ? I can see this can be easily done using MQ native api

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to set a custom/user property? If so, you can do that using SetXXXXProperty (where XXX denotes data type) method of Message class. For example

```
ITextMessage textMessage = session.CreateTextMessage("Message with custom properties");
textMessage.SetStringProperty("Country", "UK"); 
textMessage.SetStringProperty("State", "Hampshire"); 
textMessage.SetIntProperty("Phone", 123345);
```

**UPDATE**

XMS .NET is JMS specification implementation while RFH is MQ specific. Although XMS internally uses RFH2 headers, it does not provide a way for applications to add RFH properties.

You may want to look at Base .NET classes (amqmdnet.dll) and code the required RFH folders to message.

Comment: I have a legacy queuemanager which accepts a bunch of data. When I see it using rfhutil, its marked as other and a set of values are defined their

Comment: Custom properties are sent as part of RFH2 header of a MQ message. Wouldn't that help? BTW what version of queue manager are you running with?

Comment: I am using XMS.net IMessage to send message to queue. My queue manager is 7.5. Also the custom set property method is setting the value in usr folder whereas the old legacy message it is mapped to other folder

Comment: How would you  attach those RFH to the IMessage? Do you have any sample code?